# Try-With-Resources example, compilation fails. What's wrong in code

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-7

```
import java.io.*;

public class TryWithResources {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"))) 
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error message on console. I am using SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) IDE version 2.7.2.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "(", { expected
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
    at TryWithResources.main(TryWithResources.java:9)
```

line number 9 is

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
```

Comment: Are you using JAVA 7? and Have you copied the code from somewhere?

Comment: System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); give me java version as 1.7.0_10

Comment: You've probably set your code compliance option to Java 6.

Comment: Sorry, Code compliance level was set to 1.6. So the errors. Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close the question due a simple user error

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran If four people agree with you, I will immediately vote to reopen.  This kind of thing is precisely what Stack Overflow is for.  It's not hard to imagine lots of future users running into this exact same issue, and being pleased to find the solution here.

Comment: @DavidWallace : No worries, I was thinking these kinds of issue should be found by the developer. It's not that hard to find the issues. And, compiler error says everything.

Comment: Actually, this compiler error is remarkably unhelpful.  I can imagine someone trying to learn Java from a book, encountering a try-with-resources example, typing it in, and getting the compiler error.  They may even have a 1.7 JDK; and it's far from obvious that their code compliance level is wrong.  Not everybody memorises all the project options in Eclipse the first time they use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Make sure you compile it with Java 7 compiler

Answer (score 0):

You compile for Java 6 or lower given the compile error. Change that in your project settings.

---

Also, since you are using Java 7 you should use `Files`:

```
try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\testing.txt"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Note that it requires you to specify an encoding to read the file...